# “Angular 5+ bootstrap date & time picker” - selection Done hide it

Tags: angular, show-hide

I used Angular 5+ bootstrap date & time picker, I need Support set value form Input box and click a icon show date-pick, when selection done remove this date-picker. 
How to achieve hide date-picker.
I tried add `(selectionDone) = "done()"` but can't enter this function.

```html
<div class="calendar-angular">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputdisable" value="" [(ngModel)]="selectedDateDisplay" (change)="changeData(date)">
  <span class="icon-icon_calendar" (click)="showCalendar = !showCalendar"></span>
  <div class="border calendar_box" *ngIf="showCalendar">
    <dl-date-time-picker startView="day" maxView="year" minView="hover" minuteStep="5" [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" (change)="onCustomDateChange($event)" (selectionDone)="done()">
    </dl-date-time-picker>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well your first problem is: you don't actually know when the user is done with his selection. The safest way seems to use `(change)`, but that could be annoying. For that, just swap your `showCalendar` flag inside `onCustomDateChange()`

`(selectionDone)` doesn't work because it is not a known output of the picker component -> https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/components/DlDateTimePickerComponent.html